# Doubt regarding the calculation of EMF due to self-inductance and mutual inductance

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

When finding the EMF induced in an inductor due to both self-inductance and mutual inductance, the EMFs due to both of these contributions are summed. However, I have doubts regarding their summation.

The self-induced EMF is equal to the negative of the change in the net magnetic flux passing through the inductor, which is proportional to the rate of change of the current in its windings.
When there is mutual induction in addition to self-induction, then the flux through the inductor changes, which also changes the current in the inductor windings. Considering these facts, I do not see why the net flux through the inductor doesn't equal the self induced EMF.

Comment: > *"The self-induced EMF is equal to the negative of the change in the net magnetic flux passing through the inductor"* No, not net magnetic flux. Self-induced EMF in an inductor is minus rate of change of that contribution to total magnetic flux that is due to that same inductor. The contribution due to other bodies (inductors) is not part of the self-induced EMF. That is another independent contribution to the total EMF.

Comment: This question seems very similar to your previous one – in which you seem to have lost interest!

Comment: @PhilipWood . Yes, but that question has a definite answer and I thought it would be messy to modify that question to accommodate these doubts after receiving answers.

Comment: Try to have a look at https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/EM/magnetic_circuits_transformer.html for the magnetic circuit in a ideal transformer and in a transformer with dispersed flux, and the relationship between the currents in the windings, the voltage drop across them, and the magnetic flux. Only equations, almost no word, but it can be something to start with

Comment: I wasn't sure whether or not you were satisfied with the answers to that other question. I've just replaced my last comment following my answer to that question, hoping to alleviate your unease.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Jan, your sentence about self-induction

> The self-induced EMF is equal to the negative of the change in the net magnetic flux passing through the inductor

is wrong. A valid sentence about EMF and the net magnetic flux through the inductor is

- The **total** EMF is equal to the negative of the change in the **total** net magnetic flux $\Psi_i = N_i \Phi_i$ passing through the inductor, being $N_1$ the number of windings of the inductor.
  Then, you can exploit linearity of the problem to distinguish the contributions of the self-induction and the mutual inductions

  $\Phi_{i} = \Phi_{ii} + \sum_{k \ne i} \Phi_{ik}$

  so that you can get the relationship between the EMF in the winding (or the opposite of voltage drop) and the total magnetic flux passing through it

  $v_i = \dfrac{d \Psi_i}{dt} = N_i \dfrac{d\Phi_{ii}}{dt} + N_i \sum_{k \ne i} \dfrac{d\Phi_{ik}}{dt}$

  Then, you can write each flux contribution as a function of currents in the set of inductors of your problem, as shown in https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/EM/magnetic_circuits_transformer.html.

A more detailed derivation below, including symmetry of the mutual-induction coefficients and energy balance. For more details of the magnetic circuit analogy, derived as a circuit approximation from the fundamental equations of the electromagnetic field (i.e. Maxwell's equations), you can find a reference here https://basics.altervista.org/test/Physics/EM/magnetic_circuits.html.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on the above description, the net flux can be divided into components: the flux through the inductor 1 due to inductor 1, and the flux through inductor 1 due to inductor 2. So the flux causing the mutually induced EMF of the second inductor is due to the flux through inductor 1 due to inductor 1. The same reasoning applies for the first inductor. However, this doesn't lead to an equality between mutual inductances.

Comment: You get symmetry of mutual inductances with arguments about the conservative nature of the process. I'll attach you a sketch of what I mean, if you need it

Comment: I would appreciate it if you provided a sketch

Comment: I edited my answered and left some more references about the topic. If you have other doubts, I'd suggest you to accept the answer, while opening other questions, otherwise we'll do a whole course on Electromagnetism in this thread

Comment: I'm having some difficulty understanding the diagram. Does Φbb=Φab ?

Comment: no. it's not. $\phi_{bb}$ is the self-induced contribution in the $b$-inductor (do not pass through $a$-inductor), while $\phi_{ab}$ is the mutual-flux, passing through both $a$- and $b$- inductors. The sum $\phi_{ab} + \phi_{bb} = \phi_{b}$ is the total flux of the magnetic field passing through $b$-inductor.

Comment: How do you know Φab = Φba ? Wouldn't the net flux have to be equal through the two inductors, Φa = Φb ?

Comment: Look at the expressions. The mutual inductions are the same, and this agrees with the definition of energy for the conservative process (you can derive it with a procedure that starts from the definiton of energy for the conservative process and go the opposite direction). Fluxes are not equal

Comment: why won't any flux through a have to pass through b?

Comment: you can also get the same mutual inductance result if you take Φab to be equal to the total flux through both a and b, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: $\phi_{ab}$ is the flux passing through both inductors $a$ and $b$. Again, the total flux passing through $a$ is the sum of the flux passing only through $a$ and the one passing also  through $b$, $\phi_a =\phi_{aa} + \phi_{ab}$. The same is true for inductor $b$

Comment: Why do you assume Φaa doesn't contribute to Φab? From my understanding, Φab results from Φbb and Φaa and isn't an independently created flux.

Comment: Take the whole flux passing through $a$, this is called $\phi_a$. Some lines of the magnetic fields pass also through $b$, and this flux is called $\phi_{ab}$, some don't, and this flux is called $\phi_{aa}$, tertium non datur, thus $\phi_a = \phi_{aa} +\phi_{ab}$. The same holds for inductor $b$.

Comment: so does this flux exactly equal the self-induced flux? In the notation I am used to  is the self-induced flux.